# PDO queryString with binded data

Tags: php, pdo, prepared-statement

If I have a prepared statement like `SELECT * FROM users WHERE userid = :userid`, i can read this SQL statement via `PDOStatement::$queryString`. For logging i want to have the string, which is executed, e.g. `... WHERE userid = 42`. How do i get this string?

Comment: Sounds like you want is PDOStatement->debugDumpParams

http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[PDOStatement->debugDumpParams](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.debugdumpparams.php) is what you want. You may need to use output buffering though as the results are echoed out.

Comment: It's important to note that the debugDumpParams function will not dump the actual values, and only the parameters.

Comment: The OP is looking for a complete, executable SQL statement with parameters replaced. debugDumpParams() doesn't do that.